# Как выделить желтым цветом выходные в таблице?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть код, который добавляет в таблицу данные из бд

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) AND (intval($_GET['id']) != '')) {
    $id = intval($_GET["id"]);
    $s  = mysql_query("select afisha_text from i_block_elements where id='" . $id . "' and version='" . $lang . "' limit 1");
    $r  = mysql_fetch_array($s);
    if (mysql_num_rows($s) > 0) {
        echo '<div>' . str_replace('\"', '"', $r["afisha_text"]) . '</div>';
    }

} else {
    $id = 22;
    $s  = mysql_query("select * from i_block_elements where id_section='" . $id . "' and version='" . $lang . "' ORDER by afisha_sort asc");
    echo '<table>';
    if (mysql_num_rows($s) > 0) {
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($s)) {
            if ($r["afisha_prem"] == 1) {
                $prem = '<span style="font-style:italic">Премьера!</span><br />';
            } else {
                $prem = '';
            }
            echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:10px; width:100px; border:1px solid #ccc">' . $r["afisha_date"] . '</td>
                        <td style="padding:10px; width:70px; border:1px solid #ccc"">' . $r["afisha_time"] . '</td>
                        <td style="padding:10px; border:1px solid #ccc"">
                            ' . $prem . '
                            <a style="line-height:24px;" href="/ru/afisha.php?id=' . $r["id"] . '">' . str_replace('\"', '"', $r["afisha_name"]) . '</a>
                            <br />' . str_replace('\"', '"', $r["afisha_anounce"]) . '
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            ';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';

}
```

Как сделать, чтобы выходные сб и вс выделялись желтым?

Comment: Попробуй вставить if(date("l", variant_date_to_timestamp($r["afisha_date"]=="Saturday"){//прочий код }

Не уверен что так, логика примерно такая же

Comment: Вот что за фиг? Почему нельзя отредактировать свой коммент? :(

Comment: а чтобы в эту таблицу данные желтого цвета добавлять?

Answer (score 1):

Наверно не умно скажу, но скажу. Как в чисто через MySQL вычислить день недели я незнаю, но можно пропустить значение через  функцию PHP getdate() и выяснить день недели, а уже дальше припаять стиль.